# How to get Microsoft Edge handling my css for 3D in perspective correctly for mouse hovering?

Tags: css, 3d, transform, microsoft-edge, perspective

I am using the css properties `perspective` and `transform` to create a 3D world in html. In Google Chrome everything works without problems, but in Microsoft Edge there is something buggy in it... I narrowed it down using this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uke8bsvk/12/

The third variant in the fiddle is where it goes wrong. It is working fine in Google Chrome, but in Microsoft Edge somehow the red div does not respond well to hovering it with the mouse by changing its color to green. It only responds to hovering it with the mouse close to the bottom of the red div.

In the fourth variant I removed `transform-style: preserve-3d` for the red div and everything works fine again.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here and how to solve it?

PS. In my real case, I sometimes have a child div for which preserving 3d is necessary and sometimes I do not have a child div. It is not really an option to use the obvious dirty work around of setting and removing `transform-style: preserve-3d` dependent on the presence of a child div.

Comment: @Pete That is said about Chrome as well, but both seem not to need it (any more) and adding it does also not solve the problem that I have in Edge.

Comment: @Pete The draft you mention is about 2D transform only. I found the one about 3D: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#transform-style-property Chapter 8 says some interesting things that could explain the problem I encounter, but I just don't manage to exactly see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a relatively clean trick/work around to 'solve' the problem: just add an extra child div, make it invisible and rotate it out of plane with `transform: rotateX( 1deg )`. See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uke8bsvk/13/

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix the 3d properties in your css, using **[Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)**. You can do it on the site itself or add it as an extension to your code editor of choice.

It will add some of these prefixes to your code as so:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
      transform-origin: bottom left;
-webkit-transform: rotateX( 30deg );
      transform: rotateX( 30deg );
      background: red;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

Here is an updated **[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/nbbya2qp/3/)**

You should prefix each and every one of your projects for the web.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but unfortunately it does not solve the problem. About Chrome it is also said that it needs the -webkit- prefix, but with or without the prefix, in Chrome it works and in Edge it has this strange bug/glitch.

Comment: Works fine for me. What is the exact issue that concerns you?

Comment: Are you sure for you the third variant is not giving the problems I describe in the question? Is the red div turning green when you hover with your mouse over the part of the div where the text is? I am using Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0.